# Getting contact information

Tags: c#, json

How can I improve this code?

```
public class Address {     
   public string house_no { get; set; }     
   public string street { get; set; }     
   public string zip { get; set; }
}
public class Contact {     
   public string email { get; set; }     
   public string ph_no { get; set; }     
   public Address address { get; set; } 
}

//Test program  
class Program {
    static void GetContacts(string input)   {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, Contact> ContactList = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Contact>>(input);        
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)     {  
        //jsonText is a string that I retrieve from a web service. 
        string jsonText = ws.GetContactList();
        GetContacts(jsonText);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is already short and to the point. One minor formatting change; I would make your class properties upper camel case, which is typical for C#. I also dropped the abbreviations.

```
public class Address {     
   public string HouseNumber { get; set; }     
   public string Street { get; set; }     
   public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class Contact {     
   public string Email { get; set; }     
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }     
   public Address Address { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: It is subjective point. Lower case is regular for javascript, that's probably why they are named in lower camel case.

Comment: Snowbear is right. They are lowercase so that they are consistent with the JSON that is coming in.

Comment: That's PascalCase, but otherwise, yeah. :)

Comment: @Noldorin PascalCase == UpperCamelCase

Comment: Not in the Microsoft book. ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to actually review here so let's start nit-picking process:

1) I would use `var` for contacts. Anyway you already have `Dictionary<...>` at the same line. Var makes it little bit less noisy.
2) Lower camel case for variable `Contacts` name.

Answer (score 0):

Since Skeeterburg and Snowbear have already covered the basics, the only change I'd reccomend is changing address and contact from classes to structs. You aren't doing anything by reference and you don't need mutable objects. It could clean up a bit since you don't need the getters and setters. Structs (IMO) are particularly useful for this type of JSON passing.

There was a good discussion on SO about this a while back: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class

Also: since the struct is created on the stack, you do get a bit of a performance gain.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx